# Retrieve and modify data

Tags: php

I am a beginner in PHP and I would like to edit a table but before that I want to retrieve the data from this table and after modifying them.
here is my table :

```
employe(id_em,cin,nom_em,id_grade,id_affectation,adress))
```

first thing i retrieved the data by choosing an id employee here is the code:

```
<form method="post"action="recherche.php">
<select name="id_em" >
<?php
 include'cone.php';
$res= $bdd->query('select * from employe');

while ($ligne=$res->fetch())
{?>
    <option  > <?php echo $ligne['id_em']; ?>  </option>
<?php }
$res->closeCursor();
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="chercher">
</form>
```

after clicking the button another page displays with the employee information:

```
<form method="post"action="update.php">
<?php
include'cone.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
try{

$requete=$bdd->prepare("select employe.cin,employe.nom_em,grade.libelle,affectation.nom_a,employe.adress from employe,grade,affectation where employe.id_grade=grade.id and employe.id_affectation=affectation.num and employe.id_em=?");
$requete->execute(array($_POST["id_em"]));
if(isset($_POST['id_em'])){
while($res1=$requete->fetch()){
?>

<input type="text"name="cin" value="<?php echo $res1["cin"] ?>">
</br>
<input type="text"name="nom_em" value="<?php echo $res1["nom_em"] ?>">
</br>
<input type="text"name="id_grade" value="<?php echo $res1["libelle"] ?>">
</br>
<input type="text"name="id_affectation" value="<?php echo $res1["nom_a"] ?>">
</br>
<input type="text"name="adress" value="<?php echo $res1["adress"] ?>">
</br>
<?php
}}
$requete->closecursor();
$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
     die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
</br>
</br></br>

    </select>
<input type="submit"value="ok">

</form>
```

I click on the edit button of page 2 this code call the function modify:

```
<?php
    include'manager.php';
    $manager=new manager();
    $manager->update1();
    ?>
```

and here is the function:

```
public function update1() {
$this->makes();
    var_dump($_POST['id_em']);

    if (isset($_POST["cin"]) and isset($_POST["nom_em"]) and isset($_POST["id_grade"]) and 
        isset($_POST["id_affectation"]) and isset($_POST["adress"]) and isset($_POST["id_em"]))
    {
        echo 'IF';
        $this->st=$this->pdo->prepare("update employe set cin=?, nom_em=?, id_grade=?, id_affectation=?, adress=? where id_em=?");
        return $this->st->execute(array($_POST["cin"], $_POST["nom_em"], $_POST["id_grade"], $_POST["id_affectation"], $_POST["adress"], $_POST["id_em"]));
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ELSE';
    }
}
```

the problem nothing changes any modification.
for the information I already test my function it works very well.
but the problem is when I want to display and edit.
And thanks for your help

Comment: You have no value `<option  >`. Also you should put the query execution in the `if` as well, no point in executing if you aren't going to get results.

Comment: <option  value="<?php echo $ligne['id_em']; ?>"> <?php echo $ligne['id_em']; ?>  </option>

Comment: Note: if the value of `<option>` is not set, it will default to the value within the `<option>` tags. So no, OP doesn't have to set the value.

Comment: Get data from multiple tables: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: And https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add to html part value to option:

```
<option value="<?php echo $ligne['id_em']; ?>" > <?php echo $ligne['id_em']; ?> </option>
```

And here better all files not only part of code!

Here first part how get data correctly:

```
<?php   
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);


// mysql settings change here !!!
$mdatabase = 'test';
$muser = 'root';
$mpass = 'toor';
$mhost = 'localhost';
$mport = 3306;

try{
    // Connect to database
    $db = Conn();

    // select data
    $r = $db->query('SELECT * FROM employe');
    while($row = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    // $r->rowCount();
        $option = $option . '<option value="'.$row['id_em'].'">'.$row['id_em'].'</option>';
    }
}catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e);
}

// Add link function
function saveLink($link){
    global $db;
    if (!empty($link)) {
        $link = htmlentities($link,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
        $r = $db->query("INSERT INTO test(content) VALUES('$link')");
        // last inserted id if you had auto increment primary key id (int or bigint)
        $id = $db->lastInsertId();
        return $id;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

// connect to mysql with PDO function
function Conn(){
    global $mhost,$mport,$muser,$mpass,$mdatabase;
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$mhost.';port='.$mport.';dbname='.$mdatabase.';charset=utf8', $muser, $mpass);
    // don't cache query
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    // show warning text
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    // throw error exception
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // don't colose connecion on script end
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false);
    // set utf for connection utf8_general_ci or utf8_unicode_ci 
    $connection->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
    return $connection;
}

?>

<form method="post" action="recherche.php">
<select name="id_em" >
<?php
echo $option;
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="chercher">

</form>

// employe(id_em,cin,nom_em,id_grade,id_affectation,adress)
```